# How to access printer in my network using wifi in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm really stuck and can't find any relevant answer on how to access available printers in my 
network using WiFi, so I can print the text file from my app.
I don't want to use Google Cloud if possible please.

Comment: @robuust because its client requirement that user can print the text without using google cloud ..

Comment: i have tried one class LPR use for line printing than i have pass the host name of my printer and port but it not work and i have also heard about iprint sdk but it paid so please provide me the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to use a printer from your device you need to have a printer device driver for your device (probably not available) or you need to connect to a print server that have the printer device driver and know how to communicate to the printer.

So, LPR his your best shot...

To have LPR working, you need to configure the LPR server (named LPD for Line Printer Deamon). If you are using a windows machine connected to the printer, you need to configure and start LPD on windows machine and then use LPR on your device to connect to the windows LPD service.

See this document on configuring LPD on windows: [Overview of Print Management](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731857.aspx)

Good luck.

Comment: Hi guys, Can I use LPR in android to transfer a file from android phone to wireless printers and get notified back from printer that current job is finished.

Comment: If you have a Linux box connected to your printer, you should try DNSSD. I'm using this solution in my house, and it's working for both laptop and phones. search 'cups archwiki', 'avahi dnssd' for more info.